# Username in ASP Web page

Tags: windows, iis, asp-classic, iis-8.5

I have tried searching here on how to get the username in ASP but it always return a 500 error code:

```vb
<%
Response.Write("User: " & HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name ) 'User.Identity.Name )
%>
```

Its running on IIS 8.5 windows server 2012

Do I need to import a class to get access to the username?

Comment: Could you try `Request.ServerVariables("LOGON_USER")` and see if that gets you anything?

Comment: Try @j.f. suggestion, looks like your trying to use [tag:asp.net] code which will fail if your in a classic asp environment.

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question, **No**.

The reason your code errors is because you are mixing [asp.net](/questions/tagged/asp.net) methods into your [asp-classic](/questions/tagged/asp-classic). To fix this use the suggestion [@J.f](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3711928/j-f) has suggested in their comment;

> **[Suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26038909/username-in-asp-web-page#comment40789054_26038909) by [@j.f](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3711928/j-f)**
>
> ```vb
> <%
> 'As has been pointed out Call is optional use or don't it's your choice.
> Call Response.Write("User: " & Request.ServerVariables("LOGON_USER"))
> %>
> ```
>
> **IMPORTANT:** If you are using *"Anonymous Authentication"* to access this page the `Request.ServerVariables("LOGON_USER")` will be empty, it is only populated for other authentication methods (such as *"Windows Authentication"*).

Comment: In .net its `Request.ServerVariables["LOGON_USER"]`

Comment: @ZeeTee That's one way of doing it another is using the `HttpContext`, horses for courses.

Comment: Also, you don't need to `Call` a `Response.Write` or use `()` either

Comment: @ZeeTee What's your point?, at least the comments and code are on topic. Also I think it's bad practice not using `Call` let's face it no one likes being caught out by [`Cannot use parentheses when calling a Sub`](http://www.devguru.com/features/kb/kb100222). The fact it isn't needed has no bearing on the fact **it works**.

Comment: Just FYI, some people may like keeping their code cleaner than it being full of `Call` everywhere.  It's not bad practice to not use `Call`, long as you know when and when you can't you use it.

Comment: tee-hee just giving you a hard time